# How to chain two nginx modules together?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, auth-request

given my setup, I need to do a redirect rule, but only if a request has NOT being authorized by the **ngx_http_auth_request_module**.

I've done a bit of searching, but couldn't find anything. I should be able to set a global variable depending on the result of the request authorization, then the **ngx_http_rewrite_module** will be able to just give the client a 200 response, but with a custom content from my choosing.

I'm serving a video player, so I cannot return any other response code but 200, otherwise the warning video will not be played back.

Comment: You could use `error_page` directive for this

Comment: I know, I tried this. But the response is given with a 401 response code and thus the player won't display the video. Like I said, the response code has to be 200.

Comment: `error_page 401 403 =200 /custom_error_page.html;`

Comment: Ok, this made it. Thanks Alexey!